# How can I get pending transactions of a specific address/contract

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, txpool

I am currently running a full node and listening to pending txs in the mempool. Is there a way to filter transactions from a specific address? I want to get a notification if a specific address has a pending txs and see which token it will buy. Is there a way to do it?